# generating chart using python or google charts

Tags: python, graph, charts, google-visualization

i would like be able to input a dataset and get SMOOTH graph. for example i have the following graph

how would i smooth this out:
[image]

Comment: And the question/problem is...? (Have you tried writing any code?)

Comment: What is your question, and what have you already tried?

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889393/google-charts-api-smooth-line-chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). You can use it to generate a URL that represents your graph. Simply download the image associated with that URL and you have your chart.

Comment: @matzahball how would i smooth this out

Comment: Oops. I misinterpreted the question. I thought the question was about how to generate the graph, not how to smooth it out.